# Form Type Default Value for empty value in rendered form

Tags: forms, symfony

I found some weird behavior with a rendered controller with displays a edit form for my entity.

But first things first:

I'm rendering a template with displays a entity. If the logged in user is the same user as the owner of that entity i also render another controller hidden with contains the edit form for this entity. The User can access this via a button which fires a jQuery toggle.

The entity has 2 textfields which can be empty, description and situation.

- So if one of the two or both are empty the edit form will display in the textfield `(null)` by default. I do not want that! How can i fix this so that the textfields are empty like the value of the field (so that my placeholder will be shown).

Here's an image to visualize this:

[image: Description Textfield = (null)]

But further: This entity (Poi) belongs to another Entity (Turn), so 1 Turn -> many Pois. You can navigate through the pois in my website.

But if the owner navigtes through them (keep in mind, the edit form will be rendered, but not displayed until the button was klicked) all description and situation fields now display `(null)`, even he did not saved the edit. It just happen by itself.

Here an image which shows it

[image: Description = (null)]

- Why does this happen? What can i do against it? Is there maybe something like an `empty value` option in the form type?

I searched for a solution, but i couldn't find anything that is nearly simliar with my situation.

The form build from my Form Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('situation', 'textarea', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('isPrivateText', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('isPrivateImage', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
    ;
}
```

The relevant part of my edit.html.twig

```
<p class="edit_form"><span class="edit_left">{{ form_label(edit_form.situation, 'Situation') }} </span>
    <span class="edit_right">{{ form_widget(edit_form.situation, { attr: {'placeholder': 'Törn Situation'} }) }}</span></p>

<p class="edit_form"><span class="edit_left">{{ form_label(edit_form.description, 'Beschreibung') }} </span>
    <span class="edit_right">{{ form_widget(edit_form.description, { attr: {'placeholder': 'Törn Beschreibung'} }) }}</span></p>
```

Where my showPoi.html.twig renderes the form controller:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 toggle_edit" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        {% render controller('MysailinglogMysailinglogBundle:Poi:edit', { id: poi[0].id , poi: poi}) %}
    <!-- Don't worry about the 2 divs, i just shortened up the code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of more research i found a solution that is working fine

I'm adding a listener to my formType which leads to the following function:

```
function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    if($data->getDescription() == "(null)"){
        $data->setDescription('');
    }
    if($data->getSituation() == "(null)"){
        $data->setSituation('');
    }

    return $event->setData($data);
}
```

It just takes the data from the event which will build the form and is nothing more then the Poi Entity. There i simply check if the value is `(null)` and if it is i set it to a empty string.

Registering the listener is also easy, it`s done with this simple line of code:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
```

This must be done with a instance of the FormBuilder, the `"onPreSetData"` must be the same name as the function above which will be triggered by the event.

It's important to mention that the Event must be the `PRE_SET_DATA` event in this situation because i wanted to manipulate the data before they're written into the form!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an empty data attribute in the Form type:

[Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data)

```
$builder->add('description', 'textarea', array(
    'required'    => false,
    'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender',
    'empty_data'  => null
));
```

Comment: I already found that, but then i receive a `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The option "empty_value" does not exist` exception from twig